# Exponent of x in the prime factorization of y?

Tags: exponentiation, prime-factorization

This is a simple one. I recently came across the following phrase:

"$(x)_y =$ the exponent of $p_y$ in the prime factorization of $x$, for some $x, y<0$"

I know what prime factorization is, and what exponents are, but I'm unsure of what is meant by "the exponent of x in the prime factorization of y".

Comment: In the second line you wrote "the exponent of $p_y$ in the prime factorization of $x$", but in the last line you wrote "the exponent of x in the prime factorization of y". Is that supposed to be the same thing? Also, what do you mean "for some $x, y<0$"? You don't usually have prime factorization for negative numbers.

Comment: Usually $(p_1,p_2,p_3,\dots,p_n,\dots)$ refers to $(2,3,5,\dots,\text{the n}^{th}~\text{prime number},\dots)$.  We know that any nonzero integer $x$ can be written as $p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdot p_3^{\alpha_3}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}\cdots$ (*with at most finitely many of the $\alpha_i$ as nonzero*).  The exponent of $p_y$ in the prime factorization of $x$ is exactly what it sounds like.  $x=2^{\alpha_1}\cdot 3^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_{y-1}^{\alpha_{y-1}}\cdot\color{red}{p_y^{\alpha_y}}\cdots$, the exponent of $p_y$ being $\alpha_y$ in my notation.

Comment: For example, with $x=1536640$ you have $x=2^7\cdot 5\cdot 7^4 = 2^7\cdot 3^0\cdot 5^1\cdot 7^4\cdot 11^0\cdot 13^0\cdot 17^0\cdots$.  You have $(x)_3 = 1$ since $p_3=5$ and $1$ is the exponent of the five in the prime decomposition.

Comment: Oh, I think I see. So would $(x)_1 = 7$ in your example?

Comment: Yeah, now I feel stupid.